# What is the difference between [[0. 1.], [1. 0.]] and [[0, 1,], [1, 0,]] in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

I tried to implement the one-hot encoding function where I am trying to do the following:

Imagine I have the following numpy array

`[ [0], [0], [1], [2]  ]`

I have converted it to

`[ [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1] ]`

However, when I used the One-hot encoder of sklearn.preprocessing, it converts it to the following:

`[ [1. 0. 0.], [1. 0. 0.], [0. 1. 0.], [0. 0. 1.]]`

What is the difference between those two numpy arrays? If there is a difference, how can I convert it to dotted version as sklearn does without sklearn?

Comment: I'd guess the first arrays have `dtype=int` while the latter have `dtype=float`.

Comment: `np.array([ [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1] ]).astype(np.float64)`

Answer (score 0):

The decimal point shows that it is a float type.
`1.` is the same as `1.0`
The comma separates different values. The last comma is optional.
`[1, 0,]` is the same as `[1, 0]` and is an array containing 2 integers.

When I try to do

```
var = [ [1. 0. 0.], [1. 0. 0.], [0. 1. 0.], [0. 0. 1.]]
```

In Python with numpy imported I get an error.

Comment: The version without commas is the `str` of an array, it's not expected to be valid syntax, it just looks nice.